# Calendar Sunday to Sunday

Tags: java

I'm trying to get flights for 8 days starting from Sunday to the next Sunday.

The way I have implemented it now is by displaying the 7 days starting the selected date from my form.

```
// set up calendar for sunday
Calendar sunday = Calendar.getInstance();
sunday.setTime(form.getDate());
sunday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1 * (sunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1));

//set up calendar for next saturday
Calendar saturday = Calendar.getInstance();
saturday.setTime(sunday.getTime());
saturday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
```

Since the max of `DAY_OF_WEEK` is 7, what do I need to use instead?
I tried changing this line:

```
saturday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
```

to the following one:

```
saturday.add(Calendar.DATE, 8);
```

I already tried couple changes but no luck.
 Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried `DAY_OF_YEAR`?

Comment: Just tried, but didn't change

Comment: What happens when you add? Exception?

Comment: No. it keeps displaying the 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
Calendar sunday = new GregorianCalendar();

sunday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY); // Set day of week to Sunday.

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(sunday.getTime()));

sunday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7); // Add seven days.

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(sunday.getTime()));
```

Output

```
Sun, Dec 04, 2016 11:47:32 PM EST
Sun, Dec 11, 2016 11:47:32 PM EST
```

---

You can create new calendar objects without modifying the existing one, by making a copy.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CalendarUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar sunday = CalendarUtils.getThisSundaysDate();
        Calendar saturday = CalendarUtils.daysFrom(sunday, 6);

        CalendarUtils.printDates(sunday, saturday);
    }

    public static Calendar getThisSundaysDate() {
        Calendar sunday = new GregorianCalendar();
        sunday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        return sunday;
    }

    public static Calendar daysFrom(Calendar cal, int days) {
        Calendar newCal = copyCalendar(cal);
        newCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
        return newCal;
    }

    public static Calendar copyCalendar(Calendar cal) {
        Calendar copy = new GregorianCalendar();
        copy.setTime(cal.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    public static void printDates(Calendar from, Calendar to) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");

        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(from.getTime()));
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(to.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I need to create my own class.

Comment: @Samarland The class is here to present a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, you should use the new `java.time` classes. In this case, you'd want to use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class, and the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class, with it's [`previous(DayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previous-java.time.DayOfWeek-) method.

Alternatively, use the [`previousOrSame(DayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-), depending on what should happen if the reference date is a Sunday.

Example, using today as the reference date:

```
LocalDate refDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate prevSunday = refDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
LocalDate nextSunday = prevSunday.plusDays(7);

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);
System.out.println("Ref. Date:    " + refDate.format(fmt));
System.out.println("Prev. Sunday: " + prevSunday.format(fmt));
System.out.println("Next. Sunday: " + nextSunday.format(fmt));
```

*Output*

```
Ref. Date:    Monday, December 5, 2016
Prev. Sunday: Sunday, December 4, 2016
Next. Sunday: Sunday, December 11, 2016
```

Comment: testing this code, displayed the days fron Sunday to WednesdayCalendar sunday = new GregorianCalendar(); sunday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY); // Set day of week to Sunday. Calendar saturday = new GregorianCalendar(); saturday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 3); List<Flight> flights = flightService.findFlights(sunday.getTime(), saturday.getTime());

Comment: @Samarland Don't post code in a comment. If you have a clarification for your question, edit the question. Also, why are you posting `Calendar` code to this answer, which is all about **not** using `Calendar`?